# Device token is nil, when I download the app from testflight..?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, apple-push-notifications

I'm download the App from the testflight then I try to login I get the device token nil..
Please give me solution for this.

Comment: are you try in ios 10?

Comment: Yes.. Xcode  8.2.1 (8C1002)

Comment: UserNotifications method implement for ios 10 notification ?

Comment: @Jigar.
          YES, we use that method and it will ask me permission of notification when I open App

Comment: you got solution?

Comment: Problem is that, Some devices it gives me proper access token and I login in to the App. In 1 device it will ask me for notification but didn't give me device_token and I can't login into the App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What function are you using to get the device token? You are probably making a small mistake. Copy-pasting your code helps.

in your appDelegate, you should have something like this,

```
// Called when APNs has assigned the device a unique token

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    // Convert token to string
    let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})

    // Print it to console
    print("APNs device token: \(deviceTokenString)")

}
```